# Git post-receive hook to update a local clone owned by a different user

Tags: git, hook, setuid

I'm trying to set up a git post-receive hook such that when a commit is received, another clone of the repository on the machine gets updated (i.e. does a `git pull origin master`). I'm using gitosis to serve the repository and as such I believe a post-receive hook will be run as the `gitosis` user, whereas the repository I want to update on a receive is owned by `www-data`. How should I go about doing this?

I've heard about `setuid` scripts but I'm not sure whether this might be a security risk? And if  it's not a security risk, how would I go about doing this? I'm guessing I would do something like make the script owned by `www-data` and make it world-executable and enable the setuid bit? I guess this script would be pretty much harmless since all it does is update the repository, but I want to be sure. Thanks!

Edit: Is there any way to do this using `sudo`? Would that be more secure than `setuid`? I mean, I don't think there's much issue with `setuid` if the user isn't root, but all the same it seems like I'd have to jump through a few hoops to get a `setuid` script to run.

Second edit: It seems like I *might* be able to do this with some `/etc/sudoers` magic and `sudo -u`. Perhaps I should have posted this on ServerFault instead, but at least I've learned a bit from this endeavor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IMHO This should be on serverfault, but here's the answer nevertheless;

Add:

```
gitosis ALL=(www-data) NOPASSWD: /path/to/git
```

to /etc/sudoers

and run the command as `sudo -u www-data <whatever the command is>`

Comment: Yeah, I kind of figured it was better suited for ServerFault after posting, but I usually saw git stuff here. Are you sure that line allows gitosis to run as www-data? I'm not sure that it does. Right now I'm trying to do something like this in /etc/suiders:

gitosis ALL=(www-data) /path/to/script

and the script does the git pull command.

Comment: Incidentally, how do you move a question like this to serverfault?

Comment: ...and yes, you were correct, my sudoers example was wrong, sorry. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be exactly what I needed.

Comment: In this case when running a sudo -u www-data will request the password from gitosis, but originally gitosis user shouldn't have a password since it's base on id_rsa.pub is there any way to prevent the password to be requested?

Comment: @ludicco: `NOPASSWD:` in my `/etc/sudoers` line does exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that I'm using **git** username, so, if you are using **gitosis** or any other username, just fill in your's!

In console with **root** user execute this command:

```
visudo
```

The "vi" editor will be opened. Add these lines:

```
Defaults:git    !authenticate
git ALL=(www-data) ALL
```

In result the file (that is opened in "vi" editor by calling "visudo") should look like this:

```
# /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults:git    !authenticate

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
git ALL=(www-data) ALL


# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
# (Note that later entries override this, so you might need to move
# it further down)
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
#
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Then press CTRL+O to save the file, then press Enter to accept the filename (bla bla bla), then press CTRL+X to close the "vi" editor.

Voila! Now **git** user can execute commands as **www-data** user:

```
sudo -u www-data git pull origin master
```